# How to bypass cloudflare using HttpClient or RestSharp

Tags: c#, .net, kotlin, httpclient

I wonder how OkHttp in Kotlin bypasses CloudFlare. I'm trying to emulate it in c#, but I'm not having much success.

Here is the code in Kotlin that does not return Forbidden.

```
private val client = OkHttpClient()
val mediaType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".toMediaType()
        val body = "data=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&appid=27&platform=android&version=160&medium=Website%26tokenf8ed3c62d0d57a5823ccbe14b802ed57".toRequestBody(mediaType)
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("https://showbox.shegu.net/api/api_client/index/")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Platform", "android")
            .addHeader("Accept", "charset=utf-8")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .build()
        return client.newCall(request).execute()
```

I tried several options in c# :

I tried this via HttpClient or RestSharp but unfortunately neither option works.

```
var client = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000)
};
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://showbox.shegu.net/api/api_client/index/");
request.Headers.Add("Platform", "android");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.2210.91");
var collection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
collection.Add(new("data", "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"));
collection.Add(new("appid", "27"));
collection.Add(new("platform", "android"));
collection.Add(new("version", "160"));
collection.Add(new("medium", "Website&tokenf8ed3c62d0d57a5823ccbe14b802ed57"));
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(collection);
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

or

```
var client = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000)
};
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://showbox.shegu.net/api/api_client/index/");
request.Headers.Add("Platform", "android");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.2210.91");
var body = "data=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&appid=27&platform=android&version=160&medium=Website%26tokenf8ed3c62d0d57a5823ccbe14b802ed57";
request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

I've also tried :

```
static HttpClient ConfigureHttpClient()
{
    try
    {
        var handler = new SocketsHttpHandler();

        // Configure the X.509 certificate here if needed
        handler.SslOptions = new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
        {
            // Configure the X.509 certificate here
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
        };

        // Enable HTTP/2
        handler.EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true;

        // Enable TLS 1.3
        handler.SslOptions.EnabledSslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls13;

        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(70)
        };

        return httpClient;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Exception while configuring HttpClient: {e}");
    }
}
```

or I tried it through RestSharp:

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://showbox.shegu.net")
{
    MaxTimeout = 30000,
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("/api/api_client/index/", Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("Platform", "android");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "charset=utf-8");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.2210.91");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddParameter("data", "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");
request.AddParameter("appid", "27");
request.AddParameter("platform", "android");
request.AddParameter("version", "160");
request.AddParameter("medium", "Website&tokenf8ed3c62d0d57a5823ccbe14b802ed57");
RestResponse response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

or

```
var options = new RestClientOptions("https://showbox.shegu.net")
{
    MaxTimeout = 30000
};
var client = new RestClient(options);
var request = new RestRequest("/api/api_client/index/", Method.Post);
request.AddHeader("Platform", "android");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "charset=utf-8");
request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/120.0.2210.91");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
var body = "data=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&appid=27&platform=android&version=160&medium=Website%26tokenf8ed3c62d0d57a5823ccbe14b802ed57";
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: Cloudfare is BGP protocol according to this webpage : https://www.cloudflare.com/network-services/products/network-interconnect/  See WIKI : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol